# Is there support for suggesting to define automatically non-existing TypeScript classes in VS Code, e.g., when using TDD?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tdd

I'm trying some test-driven development (TDD) in VSCode with TypeScript (currently using `jasmine` but it really makes little difference to me what TDD framework).

So I write a spec (test) file `X.spec.ts` to test a non-existent `X.ts`, e.g.,

```js
describe("X ", () => {
    it("first test", () => {
        var x = new X();
        expect(x.getSomething(1)).toBe(1);
    })
})
```

The VSCode editor (1.40.1) on Windows 10 shows me a red-underlined `X` (because `X.ts` is not defined anywhere). The only suggestion is for me to rename it to `x`.

[image]

In other IDEs I've used (Eclipse and IntelliJ with Java), the IDE can figure out from `new X()` that the class is missing and propose a definition.

I know VSCode will do this for non-existing methods in TypeScript, but the class has to already exist and be imported. For example, I have to create a file `src/X.ts` and minimally export `X`:

```
export class X {}
```

At the top of `spec/X.spec.ts` the module must be imported:

```
import { X } from "../src/X";
```

Then VSCode can suggest creating the undefined method in that module as follows:

[image]

It seems it's not much more to get it to work for a `new X()`.

Is this feature supposed to be part of VSCode with TypeScript? Does it require some plug-in? Should I be asking on their github repository instead? I was following [their advice to start with Stack Overflow](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose).

Answer (score -1):

Typescript / javascript is not a class-based programming language like Java, so you won't find a official support for it.

Comment: I updated my question to show how it works for methods and how it's not much boilerplate that needs to be done. If there's official support for method-adding in TypeScript, why not modules?

Comment: A module can be anything, not just class, and in 90 percent of cases, it is not.

Comment: Looking at [TypeScript files with class definitions on github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22export+class%22+language%3ATypeScript&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=TypeScript&l=) I get your point. I still think the IDE could make a reasonable guess, however. The guy who created JUnit is (or at least was) leading the development :)